# I am trying to create an array using data from a file

Tags: java

This is what I have so far....

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String DATA_FILE = "payroll_problem.txt";
      Scanner scan = null;
      try
      {
       scan = new Scanner(new File(DATA_FILE));
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
       System.err.printf("Could not open file \"%s\".\n", DATA_FILE);
      }
    int [] arr = new int[scan.nextInt()];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }   

    scan.close();
}
```

I keep getting error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at fvse.main(fvse.java:22)
```

The five ints stand for how many hours the person has worked from Monday-Friday.  Here is the data file.

```
Mohnan  Maria        8 8 8 9 8 10.01
Blue   Shelly        8 10 8 8 6  10.00
Black  8 8 8 8 8 23.0
Fortuna Jorge   5 5 5 5 5 10.10
Jones Mitchel   10 5.5 10 10 10 15.05
Olafson Sven    10 10 10 10 10  10.00
Cruz Astrid 1 1 1 1 1 20.50.3
Adler Irene 10 12 8 8 8  22.50
```

Comment: Please post a fragment of your data file. Indent it four spaces as if it were code, so that we could see individual lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem happen because you call `scan.nextInt()` but your input file actually contains string/characters.

Either add the integer indicating the number of lines on the top of your input file, or change your code read by line (eg: using `BufferredReader.readLine()`)

If you choose the former, make sure you also read the first and last name using two invocation of `scan.next()`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading your file for integers, but more than likely that file is filled with strings or characters.

Edit: Try scanning for lines or characters, or just using a FileInputStream, and then parsing the data once it's been loaded in.

Edit: Now that i've seen your data file, I would read in the file using standard file input practices (check out http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42 if you need a tutorial on that). Then split the string based on spaces, and go through each string in your new string array and handle the data. The first 2 strings being names, and then integers until you get another name, or the end of the string.